# How to find all the keywords saved in a file using /g when searching file contents using findstr?

Tags: windows, cmd, findstr

I have a text file (filelist.txt) with all the filenames like

```
a.cpp
b.cpp
...
```

Also a text file (projectslist.txt) with all the text files I want to search in, like:

```
d:\aa.vcproj
d:\bb.vcproj
...
```

I am using the findstr command like this:

`findstr /i /f:projectslist.txt /g:filelist.txt`

This command doesn't return anything and no error either.

but the following command works perfectly fine:

`findstr /i /f:projectslist.txt a.cpp`

How can I use the /g option in this case?

Comment: seems to work fine for me. Please elaborate...